# how to get value from jquery $each loop from model attribute value

Tags: jquery

I want to get value from model base data in jQuery.

Here is my  code

```js
 var items="${uomList}"  
   Note: items array like // [CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM1, codDes=EACH], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM2, codDes=KG], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM3, codDes=LITER]]

$.each(items, function(key,val) { 
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to get  softcode & codDes value from array.

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: @QuentinVeron hello sir, I want to get values from the array which values can use in page

Comment: So you have a string, or I do not understand something?

Comment: @doox911 I have values from   var items="${uomList}"

Comment: `"[CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM1, codDes=EACH], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM2, codDes=KG], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM3, codDes=LITER]]"` === string, no?

Comment: @doox911 i have updated code. array is look like [CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM1, codDes=EACH], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM2, codDes=KG], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM3, codDes=LITER]]

Comment: `var items=[CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM1, codDes=EACH], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM2, codDes=KG], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM3, codDes=LITER]];` - So you can not declare an array

Comment: @ doox911 it is populated from model attribute in java spring boot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195021/discussion-between-doox911-and-enamul-haque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a job for jquery. uomList is a string so you can use standard javascript string splitting and arrays:

```js
var items = "[CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM1, codDes=EACH], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM2, codDes=KG], CodMasterModel [softcode=UOM3, codDes=LITER]]";

items = items.split('[').join('').split(']').join('').split('CodMasterModel');

console.log('items', items);

items.forEach(function(c) {
  if (c) {
    var pcs = c.trim().split(',');
    var softCode = pcs[0].split('=')[1];
    var codDes = pcs[1].split('=')[1];
    console.log(softCode, codDes);
  }
});
```

There's probably a sweet regex to do this in one line but this gets the job done.

https://jsfiddle.net/p7c6k2tm/1/

Comment: Why not convert to json, and simply decoding.

Comment: Because it's not a valid json string

Comment: I meant the author of the question.